# How can I include several qqplots with ggplot2 using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this code, and I can get the qqplot for each column of my data. However, I do not know how to combine the `qqplots` together by `facet_wrap` with `ggplot2`

The data

```
> head(X)
  V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
1  1 1889 1651 1561 1778
2  2 2493 2048 2087 2197
3  3 2119 1700 1815 2222
4  4 1645 1627 1110 1533
5  5 1976 1916 1614 1883
6  6 1712 1712 1439 1546
```

I need to to do a qqplot for V2,V3,V4,V5 I am using this code for each variable

```
q1<-qqnorm(X$V2, pch = 20, main="QQPlot for V2")
```

Also I can do it by this

```
ggplot(X, aes(sample = V2)) +stat_qq() + stat_qq_line()
```

I do not know how to use facet in ggplot2 to combine all the qqplots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stack` to transform the data into the long format.

```
X2 <- stack(X)

ggplot(X2, aes(sample = values)) +
  stat_qq() +
  stat_qq_line() +
  facet_wrap( ~ ind)
```

[image]